# The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Cuando quiero guardar la edicion de un registro, es decir, al presionar sobre el boton guardar, me salta el siguiente error:

> The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

Aqui dejo el codigo del edit.blade donde sucede el error

```
{!!Form::model($contacto,['method'=>'PATCH','route'=> 
                         ['agenda.update',$contacto->idagenda], 'files'=>'true'])!!}
            {{Form::token()}}
```

Y aqui dejo el codigo del controller en la parte de las funciones edit y update:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $contacto = Agenda::findOrFail($id);

        $pmedicamentos = DB::table('pmedicamentos')->get();
        $medicamentos = DB::table('medicamentos')->get();
        $prestadores = DB::table('prestador_seguro')->get();
        $laboratorios = DB::table('laboratorios')->get();

        return view("/agenda.edit", [
            "contacto" => $contacto,
            "pmedicamentos" => $pmedicamentos,
            "medicamentos" => $medicamentos,
            "prestadores" => $prestadores,
            "laboratorios" => $laboratorios
        ]);
    }

    public function update(AgendaFormRequest $request,$id)
    {

        $contacto=Agenda::findOrFail($id);

        $contacto->idpmed=$request->get('idpmed');
        $contacto->idmedicamento=$request->get('idmedicamento');
        $contacto->idprestador=$request->get('idprestador');
        $contacto->Telefono=$request->get('Telefono');
        $contacto->Parentesco=$request->get('Parentesco');
        $contacto->Nombre_Parentesco=$request->get('Nombre_Parentesco');
        $contacto->idlaboratorio=$request->get('idlaboratorio');
        $contacto->Condicion='1';
        $contacto->update();

        return Redirect::to('/agenda');
    }
```

Comment: le estas pasando patch y te dice claramente que solo soporta GET, HEAD, POST...

Comment: la ruta es: Route::resource('/agenda','AgendaController');

Comment: Yo acabo de tener el mismo problema hace una semana atrás, y el error erradicaba en el id del registro a editar.. te aconsejo compararlo con tu base de datos. Y si tu error ya fue solucionado hasta la fecha solo ignora este mensaje. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los formularios html, solo admiten 2 verbos HTTP que son GET y POST y que son los únicos parámetros que puede tomar el atributo method de un formulario ([form doc mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/form#Atributos)).

Por lo que la definición de la etiqueta form del formulario debe ser en este caso como POST:

```
{!!Form::model($contacto,['method'=>'POST','route'=>['agenda.update',$contacto->idagenda], 'files'=>'true'])!!}
```

Dado que Lavarel nos permite utilizar cualquier otro verbo, debemos indicarle a Laravel que verbo se pretende usar, para esto utilizamos un campo oculto llamado '_method' por ejemplo, con Larvel collective podemos hacer algo así:

```
{!! Form::model($contacto, ['method'=>'POST','route'=>['agenda.update', $contacto->idagenda], 'files'=>'true']) !!}
  {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

o

```
{!! Form::model($contacto, ['method'=>'POST','route'=>['agenda.update', $contacto->idagenda], 'files'=>'true']) !!}
  {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'PATCH') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

o en un formulario sin laravel collective

```
<form method="POST" action="mi_ruta" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
</from>
```

Laravel por defecto al utilizar `Route::resource()` admite los verbos PUT y PATCH, ademas el formulario deberá incluir el token CSRF en un campo oculto tambien.

Documentación: [Basic Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#basic-routing), [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf)

Comment: Disculpa, donde debo colocar esto que tu me dices?  <form method="POST" action="muruta" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">

Comment: @Laude Como ya tienes la etiqueta form con laravel collective, no te hace falta esa parte. simple mente utiliza uno de los otros 2 ejemplos uno es para `PUT` y el otro para `PATCH`. En principio puedes utilizar cualquiera de los 2 aun que yo personalmente prefiero PUT. Eso seria a modificar en tu vista `edit.blade.php`

Comment: Laravel Collective permite pasar como método directamente `PUT` o `PATCH`, automáticamente crea el input hidden `_method`. [Dcoumentación](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.6/html.md#opening-a-form).

Answer (score 2):

Deberás usar por ejemplo una directiva de Blade, de este modo:

```
@method('PATCH')
```

O puedes auxiliarte del helper: `method_field` para generar un campo de tipo *hidden* e indicar el verbo a usar:

```
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

y en tu código donde en un array estableces que método usar, deberías tener lo siguiente:

```
'method'=>'POST'
```